# How Do I deploy a DMN file in Activiti through activiti Rest API

Tags: activiti

Hello I have created an Decision file (.DMN) with the new activiti-app designer (version 6.0.0), alongside a process. And associated it with on of my process.The process with DMN file is well on the activiti-app but when deploying the Process file with Activiti Rest API not able to run the process..?

on executing the process getting below Error:--

02:56:29,130 [http-nio-8084-exec-3] ERROR org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext  - Error while closing command context
java.lang.NullPointerException

02:56:29,438 [http-nio-8084-exec-3] ERROR org.activiti.rest.exception.ExceptionHandlerAdvice  - Unhandled exception
java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 1):

The Process Application package that is produced by the activiti-app is not compatible with the standard (Community) deployment ReST API.

You should use the deployment endpoint from the activiti-app ReST API.
The App definition endpoint is described by the following class:

./activiti-app-rest/src/main/java/org/activiti/app/rest/editor/AppDefinitionResource.java

Hope this helps.
Greg